# Is it possible to _define_ a CSS Variable (Custom Property) using itself?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

In my SCSS I have:

```
$padding: 1em;

:root {
  // set to self if specified in HTML body tag, default to SCSS value
  --padding: var(--padding, $padding);
}
```

and later

```css
.padding--top {
  padding-top: var(--padding);
}
```

and in my HTML I **sometimes** have:

```html
<body style="--padding: 3em;">
```

but it doesn't work if `--padding` hasn't been set in the HTML body tag.

Am I missing something or is this a limitation/bug in CSS?

Comment: what are you trying to do? what does it mean define a variable by itself?

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact same question earlier and there was a discussion in the comments about what you were trying to do?

Comment: @TemaniAfif If the variable has been defined already, use that value, else use the SCSS value.

Comment: @disinfor Yes, I thought it would be cleaner to clarify the question.

Comment: it seems you are over-complicating a simple task. (1) define the variable inside root using the SASS one (2) any definition of the variable done later will override it --> you have what you want